# Why can this object not be serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, for my Bukkit Plugin, I need the following java class (NewItem.java) to be serializable, but it is not. It gives me the error when my plugin tries to save it:

```
16:33:23 [SEVERE] java.io.NotSerializableException: org.bukkit.inventory.ItemSta
ck
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown
Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown S
ource)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown So
urce)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknow
n Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown
Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown S
ource)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown So
urce)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknow
n Source)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.SaveLoadAPI.s
ave(SaveLoadAPI.java:16)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.MakeYourOwnBl
ocks.onDisable(MakeYourOwnBlocks.java:60)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlug
in.java:219)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin
(JavaPluginLoader.java:481)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(S
implePluginManager.java:400)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(
SimplePluginManager.java:393)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.clearPlugins(Si
mplePluginManager.java:434)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.reload(Craf
tServer.java:563)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:184)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(Rel
oadCommand.java:23)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCo
mmandMap.java:186)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchCom
mand(CraftServer.java:514)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchSer
verCommand(CraftServer.java:506)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.al(Dedica
tedServer.java:260)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.r(Dedicat
edServer.java:225)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.q(Minecra
ftServer.java:494)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.run(Minec
raftServer.java:427)
16:33:23 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ThreadServerApplication.r
un(SourceFile:849)
```

The source code for the NewItem.java is here:

```
package com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationSection;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe;

public class NewItem implements Serializable
{
   public int id;
 public byte data;
  public int damage;
 public String name;
    public List<String> lore;
    public List<List<String>> commands;
    public NewItem(List<String> lore, String name, int itemid, byte itemdata, List<List<String>> lines, int damage, boolean hasRecipe, ConfigurationSection section)
 {
      id = itemid;
       data = itemdata;
       this.name = name;
      this.damage = damage;
      this.lore = lore;
      commands = lines;
      ItemStack stack;
       if(data != 0)
      {
          stack = new ItemStack(id, data);
       }
      else
       {
          stack = new ItemStack(id);
     }
      if(hasRecipe)
      {
      try
        {
      ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(stack);
     String r1 = section.getString("items."+name+".r1");
        String r2 = section.getString("items."+name+".r2");
        String r3 = section.getString("items."+name+".r3");
        List<Integer> defines = section.getIntegerList("items."+name+".defines");
        Character[] chars = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
     List<Character> charlist = Arrays.asList(chars);
     for(int defined : defines)
     {
          Material md = Material.getMaterial(defined);
           
           recipe.setIngredient(charlist.get(0), md);
     }
      String[] rows = {r1, r2, r3};
      recipe.shape(rows);
        Bukkit.addRecipe(recipe);
      }
      catch(Exception error)
     {
          
       }
      }
  }
  public NewItem(List<String> lore, String name, int itemid, List<List<String>> lines, int damage, boolean hasRecipe, ConfigurationSection section)
    {
      this(lore, name, itemid, (byte)0, lines, damage, hasRecipe, section);
  }
  public Logger getLogger()
  {
      return Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("MakeYourOwnBlocks").getLogger();
 }
  public int getItem()
   {
      return id;
 }
  public String getName()
    {
      return name;
   }
  public boolean onRightClick(Player p, boolean right, boolean block)
    {
      int isright; 
      int isblock;
       if(right)
      {
          isright = 1;
       }
      else
       {
          isright = 0;
       }
      if(block)
      {
          isblock = 1;
       }
      else
       {
          isblock = 0;
       }
      try
        {
          List<String> cmds = commands.get(0);
         for(String line : cmds)
            {
              line = line.replaceAll("\\<block\\>", String.valueOf(isblock));
                line = line.replaceAll("\\<right\\>", String.valueOf(isright));
                String[] segments = line.split(" ");
             String cmd = segments[0];
              List<String> rest = Arrays.asList(segments);
             getLogger().info(String.valueOf(rest));
                rest.remove(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(String stst : rest)
                {
                  sb.append(stst);
               }
              String reststr = sb.toString();
                if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("cmd"))
              {
                  Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), reststr);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("setblock"))
             {
                  Block b = p.getWorld().getBlockAt(Integer.parseInt(rest.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(rest.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(rest.get(2)));
                    b.setTypeId(Integer.parseInt(rest.get(3)));
                    if(rest.size() > 4)
                 {
                      b.setData((byte)Integer.parseInt(rest.get(5)));
                    }
              }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("say"))
              {
                  p.sendMessage(reststr);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("kill"))
             {
                  p.setHealth(0);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("hurt"))
             {
                  p.setHealth(p.getHealth()-Integer.parseInt(rest.get(0)));
              }
          }
      }
      catch(Exception error)
     {
          error.printStackTrace();
           return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
  public boolean onLeftClick(Player p, boolean right, boolean block)
 {
      int isright; 
      int isblock;
       if(right)
      {
          isright = 1;
       }
      else
       {
          isright = 0;
       }
      if(block)
      {
          isblock = 1;
       }
      else
       {
          isblock = 0;
       }
      try
        {
          List<String> cmds = commands.get(1);
         for(String line : cmds)
            {
              line.replaceAll("\\<block\\>", String.valueOf(isblock));
               line.replaceAll("\\<right\\>", String.valueOf(isright));
               String[] segments = line.split(" ");
             String cmd = segments[0];
              List<String> rest = Arrays.asList(segments);
             rest.remove(rest.get(0));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(String stst : rest)
                {
                  sb.append(stst);
               }
              String reststr = sb.toString();
                if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("cmd"))
              {
                  Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), reststr);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("setblock"))
             {
                  Block b = p.getWorld().getBlockAt(Integer.parseInt(rest.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(rest.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(rest.get(2)));
                    b.setTypeId(Integer.parseInt(rest.get(3)));
                    if(rest.size() > 4)
                 {
                      b.setData((byte)Integer.parseInt(rest.get(5)));
                    }
              }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("say"))
              {
                  p.sendMessage(reststr);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("kill"))
             {
                  p.setHealth(0);
                }
              if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("hurt"))
             {
                  p.setHealth(p.getHealth()-Integer.parseInt(rest.get(0)));
              }
          }
      }
      catch(Exception error)
     {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're getting the same error message after adding `implements Serializable`. Perhaphs it shows the error on some other object? Either that, or you're facing a weird versioning issue (try clean&build).

Comment: Check my comment, you were right

Comment: Now I just need to get around ItemStack being unserializable.

Comment: Good News! I was successful after a little casting and re-type-setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class NewItem implements Serializable
```

From JavaDoc:

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
>   All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The
>   serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to
>   identify the semantics of being serializable.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think your right. It seamed like there was no diference in the error at first glance. The only problem is it is saying the unserializable object is one of the base objects in the Bukkit. The classic ItemStack. Should I try to get around this by creating a class extending ItemStack and implenting Serializable while changing nothing?

Comment: @TomMaran this may not work, one of the internal objects being not serializable. You can try to, however. If this fails, you'll need to store the data in some other way (look into `transient`, for starters)

Answer (score 3):

mark it as Serializable by implementing [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface

Answer (score 2):

You use some `List`s. `List` does not implement `Serializable`.
[Not all `List`-implementations may be `Serializable`]

I would try to use `ArrayList` which implements `Serializable`.

Of cause `NewItem` must also implement `Serializable`.

Comment: I would guess `ItemStack` is not isomorphic to / interchangeable with an `ArrayList`

Comment: `ItemStack` has a static `serialize()` and `deserialize(Map<String,Object> args)' to transorm trom / to a `Map`

Comment: Then it looks like a bug that it does not implement `Serializable` (or have a subclass that does) as well.

Comment: It seams the package has its own serializable-variant `ConfigurationSerializable`. You will need to have a look at the documentation how to use it.